# Listener not receiving ApplicationPreparedEvent

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 1.5.4 app that registers a log appender at startup, thanks to a listener, and it works with the solution explained here [register custom log appender in spring boot starter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810352/register-custom-log-appender-in-spring-boot-starter) . The listener is part of a starter that I have written, and my app with @EnableAutoConfiguration works as expected.

I have 2 other applications using the same Spring Boot version for which I would like to use the same starter. I believe they have more or less the same config as the working application, but the *onApplicationEvent* method never gets called and therefore my log appender isn’t registered. Below is my configuration + listener class .

I have put a breakpoint in supportsEventType method and for all the events that get passed there, none is of type ApplicationPreparedEvent like in my first app.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MetricProperties.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MetricsAutoConfiguration implements GenericApplicationListener {

private final MetricProperties metricProperties;
private boolean addedCustomAppender = false;

public MetricsAutoConfiguration(MetricProperties metricProperties) {
    this.metricProperties = metricProperties;
}


@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "metrics.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public EventsPublisher metricPublisher() {
    metricProperties.validate();
    return new EventsPublisher(metricProperties);
}



@Override

public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
    if (metricProperties.isEnabled() && !addedCustomAppender) {

        ApplicationPreparedEvent applicationEvent = (ApplicationPreparedEvent) event;
        EventsPublisher eventPublisher = applicationEvent.getApplicationContext().getBean(EventsPublisher.class);

    //register the log appender
    // removed for brevity

        addedCustomAppender = true;
    }
}


@Override
public int getOrder() {
    // this must be higher than LoggingApplicationListener.DEFAULT_ORDER
    return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 21;
}

@Override
public boolean supportsEventType(ResolvableType eventType) {

    return  ApplicationPreparedEvent.class.isAssignableFrom(eventType.getRawClass());
}

@Override
public boolean supportsSourceType(Class<?> sourceType) {
    return true;
}
```

}

In the application for which it works, I see that 3 ApplicationPreparedEvent are built, and supportsEventsType returns true twice (and onApplicationEvent is called twice, with the same event) : this happens after the 3rd ApplicationPreparedEvent is built, not before.

The app annotations are :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableBinding(OutPutChannel.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration.class)
@IntegrationComponentScan
```

For the other applications for which it doesn’t work, I observe that only 1 ApplicationPreparedEvent is built at startup and it doesn’t trigger the listener, because supportsEventsType is called but never returns true :

- For the first app, it’s called successively by :

  - org.springframework.boot.builder.ParentContextApplicationContextInitializer$ParentContextAvailableEvent (twice)
  - org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent (twice)
  - org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent (twice)

the app annotations are :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration.class,
    JestAutoConfiguration.class})
```

- For the second app :

  - org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent (twice)
  - org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent (twice)
  - org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent (twice)

with annotations :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = JestAutoConfiguration.class)
```

For both, not trace of ApplicationPreparedEvent being "tested" by the listener...

Any hint ? I’m quite puzzled…

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing/adding dependencies one by one and comparing each time, I have found what makes it work (or not), even though I don't understand why yet...

For my application to register the listener properly, I need to have a dependency to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

It doesn't make much sense, but there is something in there that generates an ApplicationPreparedEvent very early, **before** the Spring banner shows in the logs. A second event is built after the banner shows and the log line saying

```
The following profiles are active: XXXX
```

with that config, I can see my listener receiving the second event and being configured.

If I remove the dependency to spring-cloud-starter-feign, then only one ApplicationPreparedEvent is built, after the banner shows (nothing before) and my listener never receives it.

---

After digging down the dependency tree, **I've narrowed it down to spring-cloud-context** (I use 1.2.2.RELEASE). There's something in there that triggers that very early ApplicationPreparedEvent that enables my listener to be registered. I've even excluded the only dependency it has to be sure :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

If anyone has more informations on this or a better way to achieve this, feel free to comment

Comment: Multiple ApplicationPreparedEvent events can happen if there is a hierarchy of contexts.  My guess is `spring-cloud-context` creates a child context and you're actually reacting to that event rather than the one for your main context.