# Is String manipulation possible in YAML file?

Tags: json, regex, spring-boot, yaml, properties-file

Is String manipulation possible in YAML file??

The configuration file **application.yml** in a Spring Boot application is reading the version from the **pom file** as

```
<properties>
    <revision>10.10.11</revision>
</properties>
```

The **YAML file**

```
logging:
  file:
    name: @revision@/app.log
```

The issue is, how to remove the dots from the revision value i.e.

> "10.10.11" → “101011“

like

```
name: @revision@.replace('.', '')/app.log
```

, so that a log file can be generated on a folder without dots

Answer (score 2):

For the general case, you could use [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) which allows to call Java methods:

```yaml
name: '#{"@revision@".replace(".", "")}'
```

You would need the outer quotes to tell yml that `#` does not start a comment, and to quote `@revision@` so that it is interpreted as a String by SpEL.

The problem is that it does not seem to work with `logging.file.name` because it is read by [`LoggingApplicationListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/logging/LoggingApplicationListener.html) & [`LogFile`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/8a7e40ce918759a5936d19341077ff15410afe17/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/LogFile.java#L115) which does not seem to interpret SpEL.

It does not seem easy to customize this through Spring Boot configuration, but you could instead define your own listener (possibly based on the one above) to define your own naming scheme.

The following question might also help: [register custom log appender in spring boot starter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810352/register-custom-log-appender-in-spring-boot-starter)

Comment: If using the above *name* value, getting the error
`Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
#{"10.10.11".replaceAll(".", " ")}/app.log.\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.\d{1,2}.gz`

Comment: @Kishore_2021 indeed, sorry about that, I had tested it with a different property. I’m afraid it is not possible to do what you ask using only yml config then. I think you will have to implement your own configuration instead of relying on Spring Boot then.

Comment: We can't use our own configuration, because the log must be created before the start of the Spring Boot Application, and own configuration will be work after the application run, Isn't it??

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Kishore_2021 I have updated the answer with an alternative possible approach for this specific case